# Simple .net portal. Easy to add new modules

Tags: .net

I am writing a simple database with web access.

I have previous experience with microsoft's (very!) old IBuySpy portal system.
I am sure there must be something a bit more up to date I could use now!

I want a simple light weight system that will allow my friend to have tabs with news and pictures etc, and it be easy for me to add tabs with my database entry forms. There must be some authentication mechanism for users, but nothing complex in the way of personal blogs or forums are required.

I have had a quick look ad DNN but it looks like a lot to learn. 
Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look on this page: http://www.asp.net/community/projects/. They list a few portals, DNN for example. But they also have some CMS's etc that you may want to have a look at. It almost sounds to me like a CMS would be better for you then a portal would. I have played around with the [Graffiti CMS](http://graffiticms.com/) system and think it's probably the best .Net CMS system. And they offer a free version if you are not making a commercial website. Another portal you can have a look at is [Rainbow Portal](http://www.rainbowportal.org/). But I think any portal system will likely be very complex "out of the box". I would highly recommend you have a look at simple CMS systems instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest mojoPortal.

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetNuke](http://dotnetnuke.com) is a good portal that was originally built using the IBuySpy portal as its' base.

http://dotnetnuke.com

Answer (score 1):

Also as an alternative, you may want to look at starting with [BlogEngine.NET](http://dotnetblogengine.net/), and just extending it with the functionality you need. I did this for the http://communitycodingcontest.org website.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to take a look at http://www.umbraco.org/

Answer (score 0):

The current MS-provided portal solution is SharePoint, but that's probably both overkill for your situation and out of your budget.

Answer (score 0):

if this is just for you and your friend, a wiki site might be a simpler solution